Unreasonably very slow playback of animations in Fusion in Davinci Resolve
I worked quietly in my project, made an effect for the text, copied it to other parts. And then suddenly the Waviness node plays as if I have 4 fps, but the framerate is all 60. Checked with other nodes - everything is the same. Even when rendering, I see that the background goes smoothly, but it is the effects from Fusion are played very slowly and frame by frame. Please help!
